# Kamailio websoket error make module websokect.so

Tags: websocket, makefile, sip, kamailio

I'm having a few troubles, when I try to make the websocket.so module in kamailio 4.3. Here is the error when I do make all:

```
make[2]: `libkcore.so.1.0' is up to date.
make[2]: `libkmi.so.1.0' is up to date.
LD (gcc) [M websocket.so]       websocket.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunistring
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [websocket.so] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 1
```

Thanks for help !!!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to install libunistring

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunistring
```

Depending on your package manager:

```
sudo aptitude install libunistring-dev
```